# Azure Devops Build Policies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently when I create an PR i have multiple build validation policies running.
Is there a way to make sure that the builds run in a specific order and one at a time.

Currently what happens is when the PR is created multiple builds starts at the same time. Which is causing builds to fail because the builds are depended on each other.

I have looked at the docs but it does not seem like there is an option for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation

Comment: Builds that depend on each other are a huge, huge anti-pattern. Builds should not depend on other builds.

Comment: Be that as i may, but the project i am working on unfortunately need builds to depend on each other. It is a real headache but i cant change it, so i have to try and find a work around

Comment: @R4nc1d Hi, Is my answer helpful? If you have any question,please feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying yet...i was busy testing some scenarios that you suggested with the Build Completion triggers

Comment: It doesn't matter, if you have any confusion in the test, feel free to ask.

Comment: @R4nc1d Hi  What is the result of your test? Is my answer helpful to your issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make sure that the builds run in a specific order

For your issue , if you want your builds run in a specific order ,I think you can set it in   **Build completion** triggers .  You can trigger a build upon the successful completion of another build. You can select any other build in the same project. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#build-completion-triggers) for details .

But in order to actually run in order, you need to cancel the ci trigger and pr trigger on the related builds, because these triggers are not affected by the Build completion triggers, once these trigger conditions are met, the builds will still be triggered without order.

> Run one build at a time

For this issue ,I think if you don't use multiple private agents or support multiple paid hosted agents, there should be no parallel running.

Comment: Hi, yes so after all my testing it does seem like your solution works its a lot of updates. But as @daniel mention its really an anti-pattern.